# Devextreme react data grid on cellprepared html

Tags: reactjs, devextreme

Is there way in Devextreme react datagrid where we can render html inside the cell during the onCellPrepared apart from CellTemplate.

I would like to display icon inside a cell depending on condition , using celltemplate i am able to achieve it at lowest level but not at groupby level.

As you see from below image and lowest cell in expanded rows i am view the icon but at group by level

[image]

Thanks and Regards,
Pavankumar.

Answer (score 0):

For customizing group cells you can use a [group cell template](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#groupCellRender).

```html
<Column dataField="State" groupIndex={0} groupCellRender={myGroupTemplate} />
```

```js
const myGroupTemplate = (groupData) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className="dx-icon-warning" style={{color: 'orange'}}></span>
        <span>{groupData.value}</span>
      </div>
    );
}
```

[image: group-cell-template-example]

Comment: Using Cell template i am display at child level, but not at summary level. Since using onCellPrepared we can update even at summary level, so wanted to check with using onCellPrepared.

When i use groupCellTemplate, the icon gets displayed at the column which is grouped by but not for the column which i need.                                                                                 
                                               What if i want the phone icon to be displayed under phone column which is not grouped by.

Comment: ok i understand. I did not know that you need to customize at summary level. This was not included in your question. Using the onCellPrepared like you mentioned is the only way i know. It is more complicated than using templates. I never used this function for something like this. I'm sorry.

Comment: Np, thanks for your support , i have raised the query with devextreme support team to check if it possible